# Creating DB Connection in controller

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qsqltablemodel, qsqldatabase

Attempting to make a GUI in Pyside6. Going through a restructure process since my code was tightly coupled. I'm trying to implement the MVC as the structure for the project. I only need one connection so I made the db connection a class attribute, so then all model classes can share the same connection. I ran into two issues doing that. The model takes a db connection in the constructor so I would have to create the db connection in the controller and pass it to the model.

```
from PySide6.QtSql import QSqlTableModel, QSqlDatabase
from PySide6.QtCore import QObject

def create_connection():

    conn = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    conn.setDatabaseName(r"/Users/user/Downloads/test/database.db")
    return conn

class Model(QSqlTableModel):
    
    conn = create_connection()

    if not conn.open():
        print("Error connecting to db")

    def __init__(self, parent: QObject | None = ..., db: QSqlDatabase = ...) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent, db)
        self.username = ""
        self.password = ""
        self.location = ""
        self.email    = ""
        

        self.setTable("test.db")

if __name__ == '__main__': # for testing


    m = Model()
```

Is creating the database connection in my controller bad practice?

Or can I remove the db argument in the constructor and just use the class attribute conn as my QSqlDatabase?

Comment: If you only have one database, you just need to create the connection, which will be the default one, and will then automatically used by QSqlTableModel. There is no need to do anything in the class level, just create the connection at startup (for instance, in the `if __name__` block).

Comment: I'll be removing the if '''__name__''' block from here. I was only using that for testing. I can create the db connection in the controller when I create my view and model instances.